# print hr depending on ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

I have a input type number as follows:

```
<input type="number"
ng-model="question.numberOfLines" min="1" max="5" />
```

This is stored inside an object on my scope:

```
$scope.question = {
       questionText: "",
       size: "",
       alignment: "",
       color: "",
       numberOfLines: "",
       htmlLines: ""
}
```

How can I make so when `numberOfLines` changes of value `(1,2,3,4, etc)` `htmlLines` gets the same number of `<hr />` as its value? I'm having trouble trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an array that has a length equal to your input in order to use an ngRepeat directive to take care of your hr's:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.question = {
       questionText: "",
       size: "",
       alignment: "",
       color: "",
       numberOfLines: "",
       htmlLines: ""
  };
  $scope.hrArray = [];
  $scope.$watch('question.numberOfLines', function(n, o) {
    $scope.hrArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
      $scope.hrArray.push('');
    }
  });
});
```

[plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sd1J9Eawn35ascGdxb4d?p=preview)